# Passing the contents of multiple variables to a bash script from an excel shell command

Tags: excel, bash

Trying  to pass the contents of the string names via VBA shell command to a Bash script but it shows the String names instead of the contents of the strings.

```
From Excel VBA

Dim Str1 As String
Dim Str2 As String

Str1 = "AAAAAAAAA"
Str2 = "BBBBBBBBB"

BASHPATH = "C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash" ' or C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bash"
WORK_DIRECTORY = "/mnt/c/Work/"
SCRIPT = "bashscript.sh Str1 Str2"

Call Shell(BASHPATH + " " + WORK_DIRECTORY + SCRIPT, 1)
```

From the bashcript.sh

```
'Run code below 
echo "$1"
echo "$2"

'When you run the code above it shows:
Str1
Str2

'instead of:
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not replacing the variables in the string

Update your VBA script with this

```
SCRIPT = "bashscript.sh " & Str1 & " " & Str2
```